# Min Max Normalization for feature scaling

Tags: matrix

I am using SemanticImport to import data as follows:

```
data = SemanticImport[
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-\
datasets/master/wisc_bc_data.csv"]
```

I would like to apply Min Max Normalization to the data in the from Column 3 onwards i.e. **[[3;;All]]**

What is the best way to do this in *Mathematica*?

In *R* I would do this:

```
normalize <- function(x) {
  return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}

# normalize the wisc_bc_data
wisc_bc_data_n <- as.data.frame(lapply(wisc_bc_data[2:31], normalize)
```

Comment: Look up [Rescale](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html). Also, *columns* 3 onwards would be indicated with `[[All, 3;;]]`.

Answer (score 3):

I have never had the time and inclination to learn the `Dataset` functionality thoroughly, so I am more comfortable dealing with lists. In that case, I would do the following.

First import your data as an array using `Import`:

```
data = Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/wisc_bc_data.csv"];
```

The generate a column-wise rescaled data set on the numerical columns (3 onwards):

```
rescaled = data;
rescaled[[2 ;;, 3 ;;]] = Transpose[Rescale /@ Transpose[data[[2 ;;, 3 ;;]] ]];
```

If you still would rather deal with a `Dataset` object, you can still convert the result to that format:

```
SemanticImportString @ ExportString[rescaled, "CSV"]
```